# Compost tea - any combination of ingredients not OK?

Tags: tomatoes, compost-tea

I want to make compost tea for my tomatoes but was wondering if it is OK to add several ingredients at once or if there are any that shouldn't go together. Also, should I add more water for each ingredient or can I combine all into one 2 gallon jug?  Most of the recipes are for something like 2 tablespoons of ingredient to 2 gallons of water. So do I add another two gallons for each ingredient or can I add all to a single 2 gallon jug?  I assume the latter.  My plants are 2 months old and just starting to bloom.

These are the ingredients I have and might want to combine one or more at a time: worm castings, bat guano, humic acid, fish emulsion, seaweed granules and root enhancer. Not sure which of these are good together and if now is the right time for any or all of these. Thanks for any input!

Comment: Are you making an aerated compost tea with the goal of maximizing the microbe content? Or are you treating this more like a fertilizer/nutrient solution. If the former, you could tailor the ingredients to favor more fungal or more bacterial leaning brews to match the intended use. You are probably looking for a simple answer, but if you want information overload, check out the Rhodale Institute info: https://rodaleinstitute.org/search/compost+tea

Comment: Thanks Sue. I am looking for more of a fertilizer. I am just worried that some ingredients could interact in a negative way is all.

Answer (score -1):

Any ingredient for compost tea is fine so long as:

- the plants drink the tea, and no human being directly drinks the compost tea.
- the compost tea be brewed outdoors in a well ventilated open space.
- if animal remains are used (fish guts) or animal manure is used, the compost gea be fermented for at least one month before being applied to the soil in which plants are growing.
- the compost tea ingredients be dead animals or dead plants which died less than 10,000 years ago (do not put coal or peteoleum in your compost tea)

Comment: Still sounds like chatgpt.  Do you have any references to support this ?